# Term for describing a stock listed multiple times in different currencies on a stock exchange

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges, currency, terminology

Suppose a stock has multiple tickers on a single stock exchange. All the tickers represent the same underlying instrument (i.e. same ISIN), but each ticker trades in a different currency (e.g. ticker A trades in USD, ticker B trades in GBP). What is the term to describe such listings? "Cross listing" and "dual listing" do not appear to be the correct terms.

Comment: There are a number of such on the TSX here in Canada. I too haven't been able to find terminology specific to the concept. Examples [found here](https://tsx.com/trading/toronto-stock-exchange/fee-schedule/tmx-listed-securities-available-for-trading-in-us-currency) include DLR/DLR.U, CEF/CEF.U, MNT/MNT.U, FFH/FFH.U, IVQ/IVQ.U. I agree "cross-listed" is inappropriate -- to me, "cross" implies across 2+ exchanges. I wouldn't rule out "dual-listed", but it has the problem of ambiguity with "cross-listed". If I got to coin a term, I'd offer "multi-quoted" or "multi-currency quoted".